# Change currently displayed database item from admin panel

Tags: meteor

I want to create an interactive Quiz. The questions are displayed on the big screen, and on mobile devices with answers.

**Template.quizmain.helpers**

```
<h2>{{Question.question}}</h2>
 <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">{{Question.answers.A}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">{{Question.answers.B}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">{{Question.answers.C}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">{{Question.answers.D}}</li>
 </ul>
```

**quizmain.js**

```
    Question: function() {
    return Questions.findOne({nr:
        4
    });
```

I can manally set currnetly displayed question from quizmain.js by changing the number. How can I bind this to currentQuestion item in another collection, that I'll change from admin panel?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you mean? When you change the number in the admin panel are you changing for all users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to make some flag property into your collection like "isCurrent".

```
{ 
  nr: 4
  question : 'you question',
  answer: { A: 'a', B: 'b', C:'c', D:'d'},
  isCurrent: true
}
```

and change your helper function

```
return Questions.findOne({isCurrent: true});
```

Now you just update "isCurrent" flag to false and new one to true from admin page.
I hope this will help you.